# How can I check which image is attached to my ImageView in Android Studio? Is there any pre-defined function for it?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

I am creating a demo app in which I have an onclick attached to the ImageView. When my user clicks on the image, it changes. I want to actually return the name of the updated image that has now appeared after the user has clicked. Is there any function for it?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.img);
String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(v.getTag());
```

Comment: This just simply returns the tag value assigned to the image. What I need is the exact name of the image resource that is in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the problem. You should use a state that change when you click.
This state will be used for loading image and displaying the name.

Android team give us [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to help with this patttern.
The ViewModel keep the state and the view observe it and change.